# How come django one-to-one field still shows previous foreign inputs

Tags: python, django

Why does the django admin one-to-one field still show the previously saved foreign key inputs in the drop-down list. I thought that it would'nt make sense as since it is a one to one field should'nt it be unique but it has other previously saved values in the foreign key drop down list.

Comment: It's not previously saved value. It's the value of your onetoone field. That drop-down column is there if you want to change the relation to some other instance.

Comment: Ohhh I think i got you thank you. That means that, 2 seperate instances of the model with the one to one field cant be tied to that foreign key since it's a unique relationship. Am I right?

Comment: If you only want to show values in the dropdown that are likely to pass the uniqe validation, you can use the the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) parameter on the model field or the [`queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) parameter on the form field to restrict the choices to unused instances..

Comment: Oh i see thank you. I thought that since it's a one to one field, django would have already restricted the choices to unused instances by default. Am i right to say this?